# NSArray filled with bool objects

Tags: cocoa, boolean, nsarray

I have an NSArray filled with bools (expressed as a number), and I need to test to see if any object within the array is equal to 1.  How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean by bool object?

Comment: Are you trying to add ints to an NSArray? 'cause that can't be done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BOOLs are not objects. Assuming you mean some object representing a boolean like NSNumber that implements a proper `isEqual:`, you could just do something like `[array containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]`.

Answer (score 6):

As Chuck says, use `-[NSArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]`. As a thought experiment, here are some other ways to accomplish the goal...

You can do this using an `NSPredicate` or using the new blocks API:

```
NSArray *myArr //decleared, initialized and filled

BOOL anyTrue = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"boolValue == 1"]].count > 0;
```

or

```
BOOL anyTrue = [myArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  if([obj boolValue]) {
    *stop = YES;
  }
  return [obj boolValue];
}].count > 0;
```

You can also use Key-Value coding, though I'm not sure of its relative efficiency:

```
[[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.boolValue"] integerValue] > 0;
```

Comment: @Chuck, yes, I'd be just a little peeved to have to read any of these solutions in real code. Fun little functional programming brain exercise, though.